# What kinds of operator overloads does Delphi support?

Tags: delphi, operator-overloading

I wonder what sort of operator overloads are possible (and with what version of Delphi)?
Thanks to [Hallvard's great write-up on operator overloading](http://hallvards.blogspot.com/2007/03/dn4dp5-redefining-operators.html), I know of :

- Add(Left, Right: Type): Type (for the '+' operator)
- Subtract(Left, Right: Type): Type (for the '-' operator)
- Multiply(Left, Right: Type): Type (for the '*' operator)
- Divide(Left, Right: Type): Type (for the '/' operator)
- Implicit(aValue: Type): AnotherType and
- Implicit(aValue: AnotherType): Type (for implicit assignments : a := b)
- Explicit(aValue: Type): AnotherType and
- Explicit(aValue: AnotherType): Type (for explicit assignmetns of 'casts'  : a := Type(b)

However, what I don't know are the names for the '=', '<=', '<', '<>', '>' and '>=' operators. Do these exist, and from what Delphi version can I use these?

PS: I still use Delphi 2009 at the moment, so I would have another strong upgrade-argument if 2010 offers these ;-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually, I found the answer to this myself, but kept the question as I can imagine people will search for this information regularly on stackoverflow;

The official description on operator overloaders can be found here : [http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Operator_Overloading_%28Delphi%29)

Mainly, the ones I was looking for are named:

- Equal, for '=' comparison : Equal(a: type; b: type) : Boolean;
- NotEqual, for '<>' comparison : NotEqual(a: type; b: type): Boolean;
- GreaterThan, for '>' comparison : GreaterThan(a: type; b: type) Boolean;
- GreaterThanOrEqual, for '>=' comparison : GreaterThanOrEqual(a: type; b: type): resultType;
- LessThan, for '<' comparison : LessThan(a: type; b: type): resultType;
- LessThanOrEqual, for '<=' comparison : LessThanOrEqual(a: type; b: type): resultType;

Comment: Page has moved [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi))

Answer (score 10):

I just put my [notes online](http://wiert.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/delphi-operator-overloading-table-of-operators-names-and-some-notes-on-usage-and-glitches/) of a session on nullable types with operator overloading that I gave during a few conferences.

It now contains a table of the operators, the names and what works/doesn't work.
WordPress initially malformed that table, but I managed to restore it.

You can also download the [full set of slides and source code demos](http://www.xs4all.nl/~jp/blog-dl/2009/DelphiLive.2009/DelphiLive.2009.Nullable-types-in-Delphi-Win32.Delphi-classic.published.zip).

In short:

- The documentation (even the DocWiki) is not complete, and note reliable
- You cannot overload the bitwise not operator, as BitwiseNot is not supported by the compiler. You have to overload the logical not operator in stead.
- Overload operators pairwise where applicable
- Be aware of existing operators
- Be very careful when implementing implicit operators

Hope this helps you. Let me know if you need more info: I have done quite a bit of production work with operator overloading.

--jeroen

Comment: Thanks - now that you mention it, I've seen your slides before. All in all a good overview.
It's a pity that the Delphi-community has to document this; I would have expected an even more thorough piece of documentation from CodeGear/Embarcadero instead.

Comment: I need to find time to get loads of my stuff on-line first, then update the right Wiki's.

Comment: A bitwise not is `AnInteger XOR -1`